# Is there a way to watch attribute changes triggered from outside the AngularJS world?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I’m trying to understand interactions between the Angular world and the non-Angular world.

Given a directive that one declares like this:

```
<dir1 id="d1" attr1="100"/>
```

If code outside angular changes the directive this way:

```
$("#d1").attr("attr1", 1000);
```

How can the directive know that one of its attribute has changed?

Comment: Are you the creator of said code?  Or is this an external application changing your DOM?  [`Scope.$apply`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$apply) may be what you're after.  More than likely though, you'll want to hand your data to your Angular code and let Angular manage the DOM changes rather than the other way around.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It would be best to make this change inside the directive instead. If, for whatever reason, that's not possible, then there are a couple of options.

Outside the app, get a reference to any DOM element within the app. Using that reference, you can then get a reference to its scope.  You could use your element with id `d1`. For example:

```
var domElement = document.getElementById('d1');
var scope = angular.element(domElement).scope();
```

Here are a couple of options:

## Option 1

Modify the model instead of making a direct change to the view. In the link function, store the initial attribute value in a scope variable like:

```
scope.myvalue = attrs.attr1;
```

Then you can change the value outside the app (using the above reference to scope) like:

```
scope.$apply(function(){
    scope.myvalue = 1000;
    console.log('attribute changed');
});
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/rg8rL/)

## Option 2

If the view is manipulated directly with jQuery, I don't know of any use of `$observe`, `$watch`, or an isolate scope binding to the attribute that will work, because they all bind to the attribute expression itself, just once, when the link function is first run. Changing the value will cause those bindings to fail. So you'd have to `$watch` the attribute on the DOM element itself (rather than through `attrs`):

```
scope.$watch(function(){         
    return $(el).attr('attr1');    // Set a watch on the actual DOM value
}, function(newVal){
    scope.message = newVal;
});
```

Then you can change the value outside the app (using the above reference to scope) like:

```
scope.$apply(function(){
    $("#d1").attr("attr1",1000);
});
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/wdf4q/)

Comment: See http://plnkr.co/edit/ESrh2v1AXBMKOGncg8TS?p=preview. I tried $apply() but I can't get it to work.

Comment: This is actually unrelated; the plunk isn't working because the `$observe` doesn't fire even if the attribute is changed from within the directive. The reason is somewhat hidden in the angular source: "The observer will never be called, if given attribute is not interpolated." (i.e. if it contains no brackets "{{}}"). Try creating a binding in isolate scope and using a `$watch` instead.

Comment: See this new plunk using `$watch()`. Is that what you meant? It does not work either. http://plnkr.co/edit/uSdbISm3WoNSi7e2ODxQ?p=preview

Comment: The `$watch` needs to be on a variable, right now it's on the literal '100' (which does not change, but only gets overridden). Also, notice the manual check did not work in either plunk. I suggest using a variable to store the original value and to change the variable directly with your jQuery. [Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/rg8rL/)

Comment: Would you then say that there's no way for a directive to be notified that one of its attribute has changed through DOM manipulations?

Comment: It's doable, but seems kind of hacky to me. I updated my answer with a 2nd option to shows how it could be done.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to test all this and come up with this very good answer. Option 2 is the closest to what I was trying to demonstrate.

Comment: using .scope() only works when debug mode is on. in most production apps debug mode will be turned off and using .scope() will give you errors @sh0ber

Comment: @PatrickLawler Correct, debug mode should be on when using `scope()`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a **Web Components** library like [x-tags by Mozilla](http://x-tags.org/) or [Polymer by Google](http://www.polymer-project.org/). This option works without maunally calling `$scope.$apply` every time the attribute changes.

I use x-tags because of their wider browser support. While defining a new custom tag (directive) you can set the option `lifecycle.attributeChanged` to a callback function, which will fire every time an argument is *changed*.

[The official docs](http://x-tags.org/docs) aren't very helpful. But by trial and error and diving into the code I managed to find out how it works.

The callback function's context (the `this` object) is the element itself. The one whose attribute has changed. The callback can take three arguments:

- `name` – the name of the attribute,
- `oldValue` and
- `newValue` – these speak for themselves.

So now, down to business:

### The code

This will watch the attribute for changes:

```
xtag.register('dir1', {
    lifecycle: {
        attributeChanged: function (attribute, changedFrom, changedTo) {
            // Find the element's scope
            var scope = angular.element(this).scope();

            // Update the scope if our attribute has changed
            scope.$apply(function () {
                if (attribute == 'attr1') scope.style = changedTo;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

The `attributeChanged` callback only fires when the arguments' values actually *change*. To get their *initial* values you need to scan the lot manually. The easiest way seems to be while defining the directive:

```
myApp.directive('dir1', function () {
    return {
        ... ,
        link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
            scope.attr1 = element[0].getAttribute('attr1');
        }
    };
});
```