# Angular -js :ng-model not working with searchable dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs, drop-down-menu

I have implemented a searchable dropdown using  this library (https://select2.github.io/), its works fine but i can't get the `ng-model` value when the button is clicked.

```
 <select ng-model="destination_name" class="js-example-basic-single form-control" >
                         <option selected disabled>Choose</option>
                         <?php foreach ($all_dest as $value): ?>
                             <option value="<?=$value->id?>"><?=$value->destination_name?></option>
                          <?php endforeach; ?>
                     </select>
<input type="button" ng-click="addDest(destination_name)" value="{{btnTxt}}" name="add" class="btn btn-primary pull-right"/>
```

**jquery for searchable dropdown**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".js-example-basic-single").select2();
    });
```

**Angular js code**

```
$scope.addDest=function (value) {
        alert(value);

}
```

here `addDest` is the function that passes the selected value in the dropdown menu when the button is clicked
I will get `undefined` even if an item is selected.

**NOTE**

when i hide the `jquery` part it provides the searchable dropdown menu i will get the `ng-model` value.
I think its the problem with jquery part.

Comment: If you share the whole code, that would be helpful.. As a general answer, if the view is manipulated directly with external library, AngularJS binding may not work properly. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17159652/is-there-a-way-to-watch-attribute-changes-triggered-from-outside-the-angular-wor

Answer (score 1):

Best solution - use https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select instead of your select.

Next solution - write wrapper directive and sync scope with select via

```
$scope.$apply();
```

on select2 change event;

Comment: Could you please give me detailed explanation of `$scope.$apply()`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39412210/refreshing-scope-variable-not-working-with-scope-function/39412556#39412556 read my answer and comment please.